# How to select columns with an even ID number?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to solve the Hackerrank problem [Weather Observation Station 3](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-3?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen) which is stated below:

[image]

I came up with the following solution:

```
SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0
```

but when I try to run it I get the compiler message "Wrong answer". I don't see what's wrong with this query?

Comment: The question still have 1 part: *exclude duplicates from your answer*

Comment: "Must exclude duplicates". Try it with a "Distinct"

Comment: The answer is right there: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/weather-observation-station-3/forum

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (ID % 2) = 0
```

Comment: Will this work in Oracle? The question was tagged with [tag:Oracle]. Don’t you need to use the `MOD()` function instead, as suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446420/3025856)?

Answer (score 5):

#### For DB2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0;
```

---

#### For Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0;
```

---

#### For MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE MOD(ID, 2) = 0;
```

-- Or --

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE ID%2=0;
```

---

#### For MSSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION
WHERE ID%2=0;
```

---

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (ID % 2) = 0;
```

- `DISTINCT` for not allowing duplicates,
- `(Id % 2)` tells SQL to divide the `Id` by `2` and return the remainder.
- Since we're looking for only even values, we set this to `= 0`, as
  `2%2=0`, `4%2=0`, etc.
- If we were looking for odd-numbered `Id`s, we'd use
  `= 1` instead, since there's always a remainder of `1` when dividing odd numbers by `2`.

Comment: This is a good explanation. But will this work in Oracle? The question was tagged with [tag:Oracle], not [tag:mysql] or [tag:mssql]. Wouldn’t  you need to use the `MOD()` function instead, as suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446420/3025856)?

Answer (score 1):

MYSQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE (ID % 2)=0;
```

ORACLE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE MOD(ID, 2)=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question would like "Query a list of CITY names from STATION with even ID numbers only" then the answer would be

```
select CITY from station where ID % 2 = 0;
```

But due the further criteria like "But must exclude duplicates from your answer." your answer should be

```
select DISTINCT CITY from station where ID % 2 = 0;
```

Comment: Will this work in Oracle? The question was tagged with [tag:Oracle], not [tag:mysql] or [tag:mssql]. Wouldn’t  you need to use the `MOD()` function instead, as suggested in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446420/3025856)?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest another solution:

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT CITY
    FROM STATION
    WHERE ID LIKE '%0' OR ID LIKE '%2' OR ID LIKE '%4' OR ID LIKE '%6' OR ID LIKE '%8';
```

Comment: Can you give some more explanation with your answer to help us understand better what the problem is you solved, and how you solved it?

Comment: This seems like it would be more expensive than the other suggested answers, and it’s a lot less readable than using a simple modulus function or operator.

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL:

```
SELECT CITY
FROM STATION
WHERE (ID % 2) = 0
GROUP BY CITY
```

Comment: The question was tagged with [tag:Oracle], not [tag:mssql].

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server using sub query with case-when statement:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE ID IN (SELECT 
                                               CASE
                                                   WHEN ABS(ID%2) = 0 THEN ID
                                               END 
                                               FROM STATION);
```

Comment: Why should we use a subquery instead of directly checking the ID? And isn't ABS superfluous, since you only want zero as a result? I'm curious about your reasoning.

Comment: Nothing wrong to use ABS in it. It is standard practice to use ABS when performing any types of arithmetic operation. Which converts negative to positive. And about sub query i tried different way to solve it. Which is successful. If any one try to find different approach they can try.